# Node.JS app.get error.. cannot get /remove/remove/15

Tags: node.js, express

In my application, I'm trying to remove a product. When I remove a product for first time, it succeeds and URL changes to /remove_category/15. I'm rendering to the same page. Now when I try to remove another product, the url changes to /remove_category/remove_category/17 and it cannot find it in my app.js. Any suggestions? Here's my code:

```
app.get('/remove_category/:cat_name', user.remove_cat);
```

In the EJS page, it's:

```
<a href="remove_category/<%=attribute[z]%>" id=<%=attribute[z]%> >Delete</a></td>`
```

Here is my configuration (in case I'm missing something):

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser("thissecretrocks"));
    app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "public")));
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="/remove_category...` with a forward slash?

Comment: change your url to root relative ie. href=/remove_category

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That solved my problem. I had to change the url to root relative.